# how to assert an arithmetic relation in Prolog database

Tags: prolog, arithmetic-expressions

I'm using forward chaining algorithm proposed by [Bratko](http://ai.ia.agh.edu.pl/wiki/prolog%3apllib%3aforward-chaining_rule_interpreter). How can I enter arithmetic rules in prolog DB. For example I want to enter age is 35. In other words I want to enter the fact(age,35).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Much depends on which Prolog you're using.

I think it's safe to presume the availability of assert/1, and the 'inverse' retract/1. The code you linked already uses assert/1.

Some Prolog requires the *declaration* of predicates to be manipulated via assert/retract:

```
:- dynamic fact/2.

...
  assert(fact(age, 35)),
...
  retract(fact(Kind, Value)),
  write(Kind:Value),
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You mean I can use two versions of fact (i.e. fact/1 and fact/2). It's interesting.